# designing of layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

i want to design a layout that works fine in different resolution android phones for example the given code is layout code how do i manage this so it looks good in all kind of android phones with different resolution.(resolution are like 480*800 768*1024 etc) can any one help me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/working_us"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/heading"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>



    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:text="@string/working_text"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        android:textSize="12sp"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/online_p"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="VISIT US ONLINE"
        android:textColor="#51bdd4"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/download_app"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="21dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:text="DOWNLOAD THE APP"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:background="@drawable/col" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Well, it does looks fine with a huge number of different screen sizes. What you don't like about it?

Comment: in small resolution phones it does not look nice

Comment: we can make a two different layout for tab and android phones is there any thing likes this for small resolution phones @Shaishav

Comment: It looks fine to me on a Nexus One (3.7", 480 x 800). There are qualifiers: for resolution - layout-hdpi....etc., for size - layout-small, layout-large, layout-xlarge, etc

Comment: i test it on emulator and also in the phone have a resolution is (480*800) but it does not see full screen in window

Comment: to solve this we can use scrollview as a parent layout or i can create another layout in android for different resolution phones

Comment: OK...I was testing in the layout editor only...can you post a screenshot because I don't think we need a `ScrollView` for this type of screen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124102/discussion-between-user2894408-and-shaishav).

Comment: This is the reason why you can upload multiple versions of the same App to the Play store to cater for different Screen types and even devices. To do it all within One App is insane.

Comment: @Tasos,  why is it insane? This is what the different layout and dimension resources are for...

Comment: @user2894408, Can you post screenshots that highlight what you're not happy with?

Comment: i can post the screen shot but after some time because this i am not near to my system so i can post it after some time

Comment: @ban-geoengineering -- its insane because google has already automated a system where it knows what phone you are using and its abilities. So its easy to compile 2 or 4 versions of the same App and say these is for this particular type phones and these are for others. All you need to do is change some minor settings in the Layout and compile the Apps. Doing it by code within one App (if screen is this then load this layout, etc etc) may not yield the same Result.

Comment: what kind of minor settings i have to changed?

Comment: you have to go by the guidelines found here https://material.google.com/ and if they dont look good for you in tiny old screens then scale down a bit -- as for hd screens the rules in the docs work well but i advise to have a version for mobiles and a version for tablets.

Comment: @Tasks I'm struggling to get to grips with the notion that creating several APKs is better than creating just one - esp. when implementing variations via the XML resource files is so easy to achieve. Can you point me in any official documentation that supports your approach, as I'm just not seeing the merits of it at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can create different layout folders in res for small resolution/large resolution etc and put same copy with different values of xml files

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For handsets (smaller than 600dp available width)
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)
res/layout/main_activity.xml         # For handsets (smaller than 600dp available width)
res/layout-w600dp/main_activity.xml  # Multi-pane (any screen with 600dp available width or more)
```

For more official details , refer [this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

If you want to restrict the following strategy can be used

If your application is only for tablet-style devices with a 600dp smallest available width:

```
<manifest ... >
    <supports-screens android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Or another alternative ways is [PercentRelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html)

Go through [this](http://www.androidauthority.com/using-the-android-percent-support-library-630715/) link for a demo code.

Comment: ok and what is the difference between last and first layout files can you please tell me if you don't mind

Comment: Check https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

As evident from your comments on the question, the layout doesn't look nice in many small resolution phones, you can have different layouts to support small resolution phones. Here are the steps:

1. You must [externalize](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension) all the dimensions (you must not hard-code them in the xml layout file).
2. Make a separate dimens for xml file for different screen-density buckets (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and more if required)
3. You can multiply all the dimensions by a factor to get the dimensions for a different screen-density.

Multiplying all the dimensions with a factor would be tedious, so, you can try [my github repo](https://github.com/akeshwar/Dimens-for-different-screens-in-Android/blob/master/Main.java) which generates the appropriate dimension-file-content after entering the factor value and project location. Following is the code for reference:

```
package com.company;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {


    /**
     * You can change your factors here. The current factors are just for the demo
     */
    private static final double LDPI_FACTOR = 0.375;
    private static final double MDPI_FACTOR = 0.5;
    private static final double HDPI_FACTOR = 0.75;
    private static final double XHDPI_FACTOR = 1.0;
    private static final double XXHDPI_FACTOR = 1.5;
    private static final double XXXHDPI_FACTOR = 2.0;

    private static double factor;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the location of the project/module");
        String projectPath = in.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Which of the following dimension file do you want?\n1. ldpi \n2. mdpi \n3. hdpi \n4. xhdpi \n5. xxhdpi \n6. xxxhdpi");

        int dimenType = in.nextInt();

        switch (dimenType) {
            case 1: factor = LDPI_FACTOR;
                break;
            case 2: factor = MDPI_FACTOR;
                break;
            case 3: factor = HDPI_FACTOR;
                break;
            case 4: factor = XHDPI_FACTOR;
                break;
            case 5: factor = XXHDPI_FACTOR;
                break;
            case 6: factor = XXXHDPI_FACTOR;
                break;
            default:
                factor = 1.0;
        }

        //full path = "/home/akeshwar/android-sat-bothIncluded-notintegrated/code/tpr-5-5-9/princetonReview/src/main/res/values/dimens.xml"
        //location of the project or module = "/home/akeshwar/android-sat-bothIncluded-notintegrated/code/tpr-5-5-9/princetonReview/"


        /**
         * In case there is some I/O exception with the file, you can directly copy-paste the full path to the file here:
         */
        String fullPath = projectPath + "/src/main/res/values/dimens.xml";

        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(fullPath);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));

        String strLine;

        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
            modifyLine(strLine);
        }
        br.close();

    }

    private static void modifyLine(String line) {

        /**
         * Well, this is how I'm detecting if the line has some dimension value or not.
         */
        if(line.contains("p</")) {
            int endIndex = line.indexOf("p</");

            //since indexOf returns the first instance of the occurring string. And, the actual dimension would follow after the first ">" in the screen
            int begIndex = line.indexOf(">");

            String prefix = line.substring(0, begIndex+1);
            String root = line.substring(begIndex+1, endIndex-1);
            String suffix = line.substring(endIndex-1,line.length());


            /**
             * Now, we have the root. We can use it to create different dimensions. Root is simply the dimension number.
             */

            double dimens = Double.parseDouble(root);
            dimens = dimens*factor*1000;
            dimens = (double)((int)dimens);
            dimens = dimens/1000;
            root = dimens + "";

            System.out.println(prefix + " " +  root + " " + suffix );

        }

        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: i used this code it show default values of activity margin horizontal fab margin etc how this gonna help me in layout can you tell me please

Comment: Some sort of this approach is used in this project: https://github.com/intuit/sdp .

Comment: @user2894408: Edit the global factor values according to your needs. Run the code in some java ide. enter the location of the project, and the output screen-density you are looking for, and it'll print out the appropriately factored dimensions. Copy and paste the output in the appropriate dimens.xml and you should be good to go.

Comment: i got the output of this screen and i wanna know how this help in my code because it defines the margin only . how this is helpful i want to know that

Comment: @user2894408, as I mentioned in the answer, the first step is you must externalize the dimensions. For example, instead of writing `android:padding="20dp"` in your layout.xml, you should write                 `android:padding="@dimen/button_padding"` and then define the button_padding in dimens.xml. Google how to use dimens.xml, only then will this answer be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain consistancy over pixel to pixel you need to maintain dimens files in different values folders likes values-ldpi>>>dimens.xml,values-mdpi>>>dimens.xml,values-hdpi>>>dimens.xml,values-xhdpi>>>dimens.xml,values-xxhdpi>>>dimens.xml,values-xxxhdpi>>>dimens.xml and add the required dp or px value as per the resolution, you have to maintain unique name for all the dimen value like 10dp in all the folders.

Comment: can you please provide me the references or any example for this